# Способы восстановления поврежденных файлов Excel?

Tags: excel, восстановление

У меня при открытии книги.xls, появляется **"Ошибка при направлении команды приложению"**
-Как сказано на одном из ресурсов, вероятно отсутствие компонента path, то есть отсутствуют какие-либо библиотеки. Обновила.
-Так же были попытки отключить аппаратное ускорение, тоже по одному из советов.
Пробовала.
-Хочу сделать откат системы и попробовать поменять расширение.
Есть еще один важный фин.план, который мы периодически пересылаем друг другу и дополняем.
**"Файл поврежден настолько серьезно, что восстановить его не удалось. Была выполнена попытка восстановить формулы и значения, но некоторые данные могут быть утеряны".**
Думаю кто-то пытался его править,  наверно версии офиса разные. Другого объяснения нет. У меня стоит 2003й. Интересует правка или восстановление документа. Спасибо.

Comment: Гадание на кофейной гуще. От файла могло не остаться вообще ничего, о каком восстановлении идет речь?

Comment: Поясните: Операционная система какая? Windows 7? Операционная система лицензионная? Офис лицензия? Вам сюда [Служба поддержки Майкрософт](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/3001579/an-error-occurred-when-sending-commands-to-the-program-error-in-excel)
С подобным вопросом я уже писал на тех.поддержку майкросов. Так что пробуйте.

Comment: На офф.сайте толком не дали ответа.

Answer (score -2):

Первая ошибка возникает, если сам файл находится в активном состоянии, или сам файл по каким-то причинам не распознается.

*Например*, при использовании разных версий офисного пакета 2003-2016. В редких случаях из-за отличающихся между собой модификаций операционных систем - хотя это не ваш случай.

Вторая ошибка более плавающая. Попробуйте [исправление microsoft excel](https://www.fixtoolbox.com/ru/excelfix.html)
Еще есть не Русско язычный офф.майкрософ. Может пригодиться.
И как писали выше "[Служба поддержки Майкрософт](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/)" в момощь